# how to replace space(%20) from - or into url

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to update url (http://abcd.com/product.aspx?product=Dual%20Core%20Processor) from url(http://abcd.com/product.aspx?product=Dual+Core+20Processor).

Solve it

Comment: Before I solve it, what have you tried?

Comment: Should both `+` and `+20` be converted to `%20`, or is that just a typo? You just solved your own question, but perhaps you mean something more general than just that single URL? An example of what you have tried would give some information about what you are doing and where that URL is.

Answer (score 2):

Use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx

This is called Percentage Encoding:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding